flutter native flash screen icon are not properly placed
`
flutter_native_splash:
color: "#455355"
color_dark: "#455355"
image: assets/images/splashIcon.png
android: true
ios: true
image_dark: assets/images/splashIcon.png
android_12:
color: "#455355"
color_dark: "#455355"
image: assets/images/splashIcon.png
image_dark: assets/images/splashIcon.png
`
Image that you want to show
i have tried using android:center and other tricks


Image With background 960×960 pixels, and fit within a circle 640 pixels in diameter.

Image Without background be 1152×1152 pixels, and fit within a circle
768 pixels in diameter.
flutter_native_splash:
  ...
  android_12:
    image: assets/images/app_icon.png /// This will appear in circle 
    ...




thanks, it worked when i resized the image
